# Validator gives error message, but still lets the form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a mini quiz made on my site and I would need to check on form submit if the correct answers have been selected. If some of the fields that are required hasn't been filled it won't submit the form and gives the error for the incorrect answer in quiz part here's my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
  required: "this is required",
  email: "enter valid email"
});

$.validator.addMethod("equalValue", function(value, element, param) { 
    var elem_name = $(element).attr('name');
    value = $('input:radio[name="'+elem_name+'"]:checked').val();
    return(value == param);
}, 'Incorrect answear');


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form").validate({
ignoreTitle: true,
 rules: {
    gender: "required ",
    quiz1: {required: true, equalValue: "A"},
    quiz2: {required: true, equalValue: "A"},
    quiz3: {required: true, equalValue: "C"},
    quiz4: {required: true, equalValue: "B"},
    quiz5: {required: true, equalValue: "C"},
    quiz6: {required: true, equalValue: "B"},
  }
 });

});
// ]]></script>
```

How can I make if it returns false it won't let the form submit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `return false;` after `rules` braces in above code

Comment: Probably you are using input type="submit" which will submit the form once clicked. If that is the case change it to input type="button"

Comment: Chances are there is some other problem - validate by default will not allow the form to be submitted unless it passes all your rules.  Please post the HTML for the form so we can look at that for issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bad script that will validate the form immediately after loading the webpage. it must be  executed upon submitting the form:

```
<form id="quiz">
</form>

<script>

$('#quiz').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // validate form
    // if success,
    $(this).submit();
});
</script>
```